# Retrieving data from Firebase and storing as annotations on a map

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, annotations, mapkitannotation

I've successfully managed to store data to my Firebase database from a form I created in a view controller but now need to retrieve the data to display as annotations on a map on a second view controller but do not know how I should go about doing this task after searching and finding nothing online.

Here is my working code that saves my data successfully to the Firebase database:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase

class AddSightingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UITextView!

    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set Date & Time

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE, MMM d, yyyy") // // set template after setting locale

        let dateString = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date))"
        dateLabel.text = String(dateString)

        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

        timeFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("hhmm")

        let timeString = "\(timeFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date))"

        timeLabel.text = String(timeString)

        // Set Latitude & Longitude

        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways){
            currentLocation = locManager.location
            self.latitudeLabel.text = String("\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
            self.longitudeLabel.text = String("\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
        }
    }

    func post() {

        let date = dateLabel.text
        let time = timeLabel.text
        let latitude = latitudeLabel.text
        let longitude = longitudeLabel.text
        let sightingDescription = descriptionLabel.text

        let post: [String : AnyObject] = ["Date" : date as AnyObject,
                                          "Time" : time as AnyObject,
                                          "Latitude" : latitude as AnyObject,
                                          "Longitude" : longitude as AnyObject,
                                          "Description" : sightingDescription as AnyObject]

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Sightings").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

        post()

        // Create the alert controller
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sighting Logged Successfully", message: "Your logged entry will now show up on the map for others to see. Thank You!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")

        }

        // Add the actions
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        // Present the controller
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Search more... this question appears every 2 days atleast..

Comment: @VladPulichev: You are correct that this question pops up every few days. I really wonder if there is a codelab somewhere that gets developers this far and then leaves them stranded. But it'd be more helpful if you find of those previous questions (one that has been answered) and mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I’ve searched for output as annotations and see nothing do you have a link you’d like to share ?

Answer (score 0):

After working on this I've eventually got it to work by using the following function and calling it in viewDidLoad()

```
func displayAnnotations() {

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Sightings").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let date = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Date"] as! String!
            let time = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Time"] as! String!
            let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Latitude"] as! String!
            let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Longitude"] as! String!
            let desc = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Description"] as! String!

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
            annotation.title = date
            annotation.subtitle = time
            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        })}
```