# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' and Cannot call value of non-function type 'AnyObject' errors retrieving data from Firebase in SWIFT 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm changing the way I'm posting and retrieving firebase CLLocationCoordinated2D, from one post per value to one post with all values, so I found this post and I would like to implement it in my own code. [Retrieving data from Firebase and storing as annotations on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434480/retrieving-data-from-firebase-and-storing-as-annotations-on-a-map) .
Im having the errors mentioned in the title on the constants date, time, latitude, longitude and desc.
I'm still learning Firebase so any explanation will be very helpful. Tis is the function where I get the errors.

```
   func displayAnnotations() {

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Sightings").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let date = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!("Date") as! String?
            let time = (snapshot.value as AnyObject)!("Time") as! String?
            let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject)!("Latitude") as! String?
            let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!("Longitude") as! String?
            let desc = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!("Description") as! String?

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
            annotation.title = date
            annotation.subtitle = time
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        })}
```

and this is the posting function:

```
func post() {

        let date = dateLabel.text
        let time = timeLabel.text
        let latitude = latitudeLabel.text
        let longitude = longitudeLabel.text
        let sightingDescription = descriptionLabel.text

        let post: [String:String] = ["Date" : date as AnyObject,
                                          "Time" : time as AnyObject,
                                          "Latitude" : latitude as AnyObject,
                                          "Longitude" : longitude as AnyObject,
                                          "Description" : sightingDescription as AnyObject]

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Sightings").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

    }
```

Is it just because it's written for a version previous to swift 4.1?

Comment: The link you have shown is far from a good practice even in Swift3, and you also mis-using `()` instead of `[]` in the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed `[]` to `()`

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
let date = dic["Date"] 
let time = dic["Time"]   
let latitude = dic["Latitude"] 
let longitude = dic["Longitude"]  
let desc = dic["Description"]
```

Comment: parse other vars as date in answer

Comment: can you explain it a bit? I'd like to understand what's the difference between the two methods. was it written for older version of swift? because in the post it worked like that..

Comment: I don't recommend using AnyObject , you should use swifty as possible use direct types if possible , from your parsing seems it's **[String:String]** , also confirm if worked ??

Comment: so consequently It's better to change to [String:String] also the posting function right? I'll edit and add it to the question

Comment: Yes , i saw it in the other post **let post: [String : AnyObject]** to **let post: [String : String]**

Comment: @vincenzo no it's not because it's written before swift 4 , it was  a bad practice

Comment: changed to `let post: [String:String] = ["Date" : date as! String`and I get Forced cast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?, it builds but what about that warning?